# Not able to send html form data in googlesheet without using script editor and google forms

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api

Here **index.html** file made for account authentication containing signin and signout button. 
Next, **sendform.html** is the actual page having some fields which needs to be stored when clicked on submit button but when I run this, the data is not sent to googlesheet. I don't want to use google forms and app-script just normal html form and javascript only. Please help!!

**index.html**

```
<head></head>

<body>

  <script>

    function initClient() {
      var API_KEY = '<API KEY>';

      var CLIENT_ID = '<CLIENTID>';

      var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets';

      gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'clientId': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPE,
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
      }).then(function () {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSignInStatus);
        updateSignInStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      });
    }

    function handleClientLoad() {
      gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }

    function updateSignInStatus(isSignedIn) {
      if (isSignedIn) {
        location.replace("http://localhost:8080/sendform.html");
      }
      else
      alert("Error in Redirecting");
    }

    function handleSignInClick(event) {
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    }

    function handleSignOutClick(event) {
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
    onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
  </script>
  <button id="signin-button" onclick="handleSignInClick()">Sign in</button>
  <button id="signout-button" onclick="handleSignOutClick()">Sign out</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**sendform.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bulk Me</title>
</head>
<script>

    function makeApiCall() {

        var params = {

            spreadsheetId: '<SheetID>',

            range: 'Sheet1',

            valueInputOption: 'RAW',

            insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',

        };

        var myFormData = [];
        var fname = document.getElementById("frml").elements[0].value;
        myFormData.push(fname);
        var lname = document.getElementById("frml").elements[1].value;
        myFormData.push(lname);
        var mobile = document.getElementById("frml").elements[2].value;
        myFormData.push(mobile);

        var valueRangeBody = {
            "majorDimension": "ROWS",
            "values": myFormData
        };

        var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(params, valueRangeBody);;
        request.then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.result);
        }, function (reason) {
            console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form id=frml>
        First Name:<br> <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
        Last Name:<br> <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
        Mobile:<br> <input type="number" id="mobile"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="makeApiCall()">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the detail information about `the data is not sent to googlesheet`?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to send the html form field data entered by the user into the googlesheet. whenever the user clicks on the submit button in **sendform.html** the data entered in the fields must be sent to the googlesheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the situation of `the data is not sent to googlesheet`.

Comment: You say, How can I make you understand??

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the detail information about `the data is not sent to googlesheet`? When `the submit button` is clicked, what happens? For example, does the error occur? Or? And you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API?

Comment: As I said earlier, I just want to append the html form fields data to googlesheet. Whenever the user fills the html form and clicks on submit button the fields data must be saved in googlesheet in a new row.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If I could correctly understand about your current issue, I would like to think of the solution and workaround.

Comment: @Tanaike  I don't see any error in console but I am damn sure there is an error when I click on submit button some error occurs in console and the error gets disappears automatically. I am also not getting why error is disappearing.

Comment: Have you considered using [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)? Or do you really need to build the OAuth process manually because you're hosting those html files outside Google Servers? (This information can help me to provide a better answer)

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable time. Issue Solved!

Comment: I'm glad you could find by yourself a solution for your issue, but please consider posting it as an answer to help people in the future, which could have the same problem or a similar one.

Comment: Answer:- `var valueRangeBody = {
            "majorDimension": "ROWS",
            "values": [myFormData]
        };`